# Visiting admin pages return 404 (page not found error) after transfer website

Tags: .htaccess, configuration

I have transferred my website from another hosting . Front showing fine but if we click on link it will page not found error ..admin also not showing so how i control my website..i checked `.Htacces` as following

`# RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]`

And added this code in    `setting.php`
`$conf = array( 'clean_url' => 0,);`

My website URL is like this :

http://tailoredsuitonline.com.previewdns.com/oceanwis/

Please share your help here. Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried to use stock htaccess? Just to test if it'll work for you? Also, question's validity should not depend on external link. Unless you are planning to keep that site forever in a buggy state described, rewrite your question in a way that will make this link no longer needed to understand your issue.

Comment: Did you try accessing a page with the index.php?q= ? For example, if you have a contact page at http://example.com/contact, try to access it through http://example.com/index.php?q=contact. If it works, then it's a problem related to Clean URLs. If not, it's probably related to your htaccess file.

Comment: yes mat pages accessing like this http://tailoredsuitonline.com.previewdns.com/oceanwis/?q=album  But i tried to access admin login page using same..but not showing admin login page

Answer (score 2):

So there is a problem with Clean URLs, as this works:
http://tailoredsuitonline.com.previewdns.com/oceanwis/?q=album

But this doesn't:
http://tailoredsuitonline.com.previewdns.com/oceanwis/album

You can log in with your admin account here:
http://tailoredsuitonline.com.previewdns.com/oceanwis/?q=user

Then go there and disable clean URLs:
http://tailoredsuitonline.com.previewdns.com/oceanwis/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls

Comment: Really.. very Thanks Matt..its working you solved my issue genius...

Answer (score 1):

I think the old `.htaccess` file not uploaded ,please upload it again and make sure the old one uploaded .put some comment in it then upload check it upload correctly. 
sometimes the .htaccess file not upload.
another reason is maybe you clean url not active, this link maybe help you about clean url https://drupal.org/node/256410.

and third reason maybe occur of dedicate servers,in dedicate server sometimes local configuration not applied